# How old is Adam in The Goldbergs? How does this reconcile with watching Star Wars?

Tags: the-goldbergs

"The Goldbergs" is a comedy set in the 1980s, originally released in September 2013. If the main character, Adam, is supposed to be 11 years old, it doesn't make sense that he saw Star Wars "Return of the Jedi" in 1983, and six years later in 1989, he still looked the same, instead of 17, he was still 11. (It is 1989 according to Barry's fake ID making him "25 years old" saying he was born in 1964). Anyway, why wouldn't have Adam aged much?

Comment: I don't watch the show, but did Adam say he watched Star Wars "in 1983 WHEN HE WAS 11"? Or did he just say he saw it in 1983, 6 years ago, when he was presumably 5 years old?

Answer (score 4):

The show takes place in the fictional time period of 1980something where everything from Jan 1 1980 - Dec 31 1989 is occurring basically at the same time. The characters do not necessarily age until they need to. Events are being retold by the unreliable narrator - adult Adam. Everything could have just happened or happened 5 years prior by our time but still occur on the same day in the show.